# Compression support for Snowflake Ingestion?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I am trying to figure out what is the best compression type to have for a bulk load of data.

What is the best compression I can do locally? Is this done for you?

I am using AWS to Stage the file first. I did see you can create the file type and specify the compression, but did not find if I can compress locally then upload or the types of compression supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best compression is determined by how you measure "best".  I would say that gzip is best because it is simple and can provide for up to 10x compression, but if load time is your factor for best then the answer might be different.

Here are some documentation links to help provide more details to answer your question.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-prepare.html#data-file-compression
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-summary-loading.html#compression-of-staged-files
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#syntax

Let us know if you have any issues loading your files.  Best of luck.